# Unityで作られたゲームがWindowsで作られた場合、Macで実行出来ないなどはありますか？

Tags: unity3d, lua

Unityで作成されたゲームを利用してコードや実装の学習を進めているのですが、私以外のメンバーはみなWindowsユーザーで私だけmac m1ユーザーです。Unityのバージョンは合わせてます。

あるゲームシーンを実行しようとすると下記のエラーが表示されてしまい解決できません。
Windowsで作成されたプロジェクトがmacで実行できないようなことはあるのでしょうか？

```
DllNotFoundException: xlua assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。[クロスプラットフォームの注意点](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2023.2/Manual/CrossPlatformConsiderations.html), [条件付きコンパイル](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2023.2/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html), [Unityのマルチプラットフォームビルドスクリプトではまりがちなこと（特にiOS）](https://qiita.com/mhama/items/a0c6b8efcb8ff06050b1), [Unityゲーム開発進捗：マルチプラットフォームの下準備](https://note.com/funsetmodev/n/nbdf479f3ebe6), [\[mipass\]PC でも Mac でも iOS でも Android でも](https://www.create-forever.games/mipass-8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「Windows**で**作成されたプログラムがMacで実行できない」のではなく、「Windows**用に**作成されたプログラムがMacで実行できない」です。一つのOSで他OS用の開発は可能です。

それに、多OS用の開発も可能です。普段、ゲーム開発においては他からのコードを部分的に多用するなど(frameworkなど)が多いので、多OS用の開発をするより、同じゲームをOS毎にコンパイルする方が多いですが、SteamなどではSteamOS(Debian8を元とするLinux系の専門OS)用に開発すればVM経由でどのOSでも実行できる、など多OS向けの開発を専門にするプラットフォームなどは多在します。

Unity自身はクロスプラットフォーム用ゲームエンジンですので、相応の開発のしかたをすればWindows、MachintoshとLinuxに実行するゲームの開発は可能です。

ただ、これはプロジェクトをより複雑なものにし、専用の開発者を必要とする場合もありますので、普段はゲーマーが少ないLinuxを除いて、BlizzardがスタークラフトをWindowsとMac専用で開発するなど、（特に経験の浅い独立開発者による作品は）ゲーマー層で一番大きいWindows専用にゲームが開発されたりなどの場合が多いですね。

もっと詳しく教えてほしい場合は、開発環境を詳しく記載して聞き改めてください。

Answer (score -2):

ふつう、WindowsのプログラムはMacでは実行できません

Comment: WindowsのプログラムをMacで実行するための何かプロセスってあったりするのでしょうか？？

Comment: @RYJ VM(バーチャルマシーン)を使わなければ出来ません。